# Type assert custom type to base type

Tags: go, types, type-conversion, type-assertion

Is it possible to type assert a custom type to its base type?

For example, if I have the following

```
type A []interface{}

var x = map[string]interface{}{
        "hello":"a",
        "world":A{"b","c"},
    }

y := x["world"]
```

Then if I try to type assert via `y.([]interface{})` I get the error `//interface {} is A, not []interface {}`.

Edit: As an answer below has noted, I can assert to type A via `y.(A)`. The problem stems from `x` being given by a Mongo driver. Some drivers implement their own types, for example, the official mongo driver implements a `bson.A` type for `[]interface` types. If I switch drivers then my type assertions need to change to match their custom types, which is something I want to avoid.

Comment: You only need to assert the type of an interface value if you need to access something specific to the dynamic type, such as a struct field or a method that is not part of the interface. If you depend on something that's specific to a particular driver then that code won't work with another driver, obviously. Don't do that then. Depend only on some common interface that works with all drivers you want to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [type asserting](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) (to) a concrete type, you can only type assert the same type that is stored in the interface value, not its base type. Of course when you have the concrete type, you can [convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) that to its base type.

You said you want to avoid that, you want to avoid having to refer to the concrete type.

To do that, you will need reflection. Obtain a [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) descriptor of the value, and use the [`Value.Convert()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Convert) method to "directly" convert to its base type, skipping the "actual" type. This will succeed because a value can be converted to a value of its base type.

Of course the `Value.Convert()` method will yield a value of type `reflect.Value` (and not `[]interface{}`), but you can get the `interface{}` value wrapping this using [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface). You will now have an `interface{}` that wraps a concrete value of type `[]interface{}`, from which you can now type assert a value of type `[]interface{}`.

See this example:

```
z := reflect.ValueOf(y).Convert(reflect.TypeOf([]interface{}{})).
    Interface().([]interface{})

fmt.Printf("%T %v", z, z)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/urlxJmMhiOs)):

```
[]interface {} [b c]
```

There's a lot of boilerplate here, and this won't be nearly as efficient as a simple type-assertion and conversion. Try to avoid doing it this way.